# Avoid to set Copy To Output Directory with new csproj format

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2017, nancy

I created a VS2017 solution using the "new" `csproj` format, it's a web .net 4.6.1 application written using Nancyfx, serving pages thru owin and IIS.

All my views are under the `Views` folder but if I don't set the `Copy to Output` options IIS cannot find them (the same is true for my custom config files).

The problem, I think, is that the output directory is automatically set to `bin\net461\win7-x86` instead of simply `bin` and the working directory of the web app is set to the output dir, so I have to set the `copy to output` option.

How can I use the new csproj format but retain the ability to edit view files without rebuilding the app? I already tried to set the output folder to `bin` but it is ignored. I also tried to set the the Working Directory value in the Debug tab but to no avail. I set the values in every configuration (debug/release) so that's not the issue.

This is my csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win7-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x86'" />

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="MongoDB.Driver" Version="2.4.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nancy" Version="2.0.0-clinteastwood" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nancy.Authentication.Forms" Version="2.0.0-clinteastwood" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nancy.Authentication.Stateless" Version="2.0.0-clinteastwood" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nancy.Bootstrappers.Unity" Version="2.0.0-clinteastwood" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nancy.Serialization.JsonNet" Version="2.0.0-clinteastwood" />
    <PackageReference Include="Nancy.Validation.FluentValidation" Version="2.0.0-clinteastwood" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Views\*.sshtml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two days spent trying I found the root cause of the problem: it was not a VS/csproj problem but rather a Nancyfx 2.0 configuration issue.

For everyone interested here are the steps that I followed to fix the problem:

- Implement an `IRootPathProvider` configured to return the value of `IHostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath` as taken from your `Startup` class
- Register the custom `IRootPathProvider` in your `Bootstrapper` overriding `IRootPathProvider RootPathProvider { get; }`
- By default in Nancyfx 2.0 the view are *always* cached, even in debug mode ([see this ticket](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2432)), so in your `Bootstrapper` override the configure method as shown below.

Method `Bootstrapper.Configure`:

```
public override void Configure(INancyEnvironment environment)
{
    base.Configure(environment);
#if DEBUG
    // Disable view caching in debug mode
    environment.Views(true, true);
#endif
}
```

Now views are read from the VS project directory (and not the bin folder) and are not cached, so no more rebuilds between every view change. In your `csproj` you can easily put:

```
<None Include="Views\**\*.sshtml" />
```